# Where is hybrid app's local storage actually stored (path) in the device?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ionic-framework, local-storage

Can someone please confirm where the actual local storage is stored on the phone for hybrid apps(ionic/Angular)?

I checked other posts and most of them suggest to use [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) as local storage is not the best way to store data. I also saw that there are/were some issue with iPhones deleting app storage in various situations.

I tried to use [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) and the iOS system logs tell me the following:

`open full db path: /Users/[name]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2A955FF-49FC-4760-94FB-B0254BB87C7D/data/Containers/Data/Application/4365F57A-6330-49CC-145F-8D7C7EC1D7EF/Library/LocalDatabase/appDatabase.db`

Is localstorage stored at the same place? i.e. `/Application/appID/Library/LocalDatabase/somefile.format`?

Full Sqlite logs:

```
OPEN database: app.db
[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 33] Initializing SQLitePlugin
[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 44] Detected docs path: /Users/[name]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/someID/data/Containers/Data/Application/someAppId/Documents
[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 48] Detected Library path: /Users/[name]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/someID/data/Containers/Data/Application/someAppId/Library
[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 67] no cloud sync at path: /Users/[name]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/someID/data/Containers/Data/Application/someAppId/Library/LocalDatabase
[SQLitePlugin openNow:] [Line 137] open full db path: /Users/[name]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/someID/data/Containers/Data/Application/someAppId/Library/LocalDatabase/app.db
[SQLitePlugin openNow:] [Line 164] Good news: SQLite is thread safe!
OPEN database: app.db - OK
```

#### Finally, is this encrypted by the phone?

I am aware that the localstorage is isolated from other apps and can not be accessed outside. I want to know if this data is encrypted to that app in any way?

My only concern is that what if user has a malware on rooted phone and they access this folder. Can they just read the contents? or they will get encrypted blob?

Comment: As far as encryption goes-  even if it is encrypted, you'd have a local key in your app.  You can't trust a local key-  they can easily decompile your app and get it.  Always assume any data on a client machine is compromised.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan so what's wrong with the key being generated randomly at runtime and then stored into the keychain?

Comment: @Sausagedioxide Anytime a key and the value it encrypts are stored on the same device, its vulnerable.  A trivial attack on Android would just to use the AOSP and stub out the keychain functions to write to a file.  It all depends on what attack vectors you're afraid of.  But keychains aren't magic pixie dust that make everything work

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I was talking about iOS, I didn't notice the op has also the android tag in the question in addition to iOS.

Comment: Thanks Gabe Sechan and  @Sausagedioxide.This makes sense, the key needs to be stored in the device and if device is compromised, it's no longer safe.